# Jenkins MSTest + MSTestPublisher don't fail build when tests fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a Jenkins multibranch pipeline project and one of the steps runs unit tests. When some unit tests fail Jenkins marks the build as unstable instead of fail the build.

```
stage('UnitTests') {
  steps {
    bat(returnStatus: true, script: """
      "MSTest" /resultsfile:"testresults-module1-Tests_${env.BUILD_ID}.trx" /testcontainer:bin/module1.Tests.dll"
      "MSTest" /resultsfile:"testresults-module2-Tests_${env.BUILD_ID}.trx" /testcontainer:bin/module2.Tests.dll"
    """)
    step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"testresults*.trx", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
  }
}
```

I need this job to fail when any test fails.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct plugin? It seems like the xUnit and MSTest Plugin do have a relation to each other so maybe you are using xUnit's MSTestPublisher which is outdated.

Comment: Someone had the same issue as you in August '17 (down in the comment section): https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround to solve this problem.

```
stage('UnitTests') {
  steps {
    script {
      resultcmd = 0

      resultcmd += bat(returnStatus: true, script: """
        "MSTest" /resultsfile:"testresults-module1-Tests_${env.BUILD_ID}.trx" /testcontainer:bin/module1.Tests.dll"
        exit /b %errorlevel%
      """)

      resultcmd += bat(returnStatus: true, script: """
        "MSTest" /resultsfile:"testresults-module2-Tests_${env.BUILD_ID}.trx" /testcontainer:bin/module2.Tests.dll"
        exit /b %errorlevel%
      """)

      if (resultcmd > 0) {
        error("Tests failed")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I execute each command in a separated bat block and add the result in a variable called resultcmd. Then, at the end, I check the value of resultcmd and force an error if the value is greater then 0.

I'm sure this isn't the best solution, but this is the only fix I found.